# How can I remove the folder name from a filename?

Tags: powershell, rename

I have a lot of files that have names of the format:

> [Folder name] [File name].txt

that live in the correct folders - e.g:

```
+- Folder 1
    +- Folder 1 File 1.txt
    |- Folder 1 File 2.txt
+- Folder 2
    +- Folder 2 File 1.txt
    |- Folder 2 File 2.txt
```

and I need to remove the folder name from the filename.

I've found the Powershell command `$file.DirectoryName` but it obviously doesn't work in the rename command:

```
get-childitem -filter "*.txt" -recurse | rename-item -newname {$_.Name -replace "$file.DirectoryName ", ""}
```

as that's doing simple pattern matching and not evaluating the variable - despite the syntax colouring implying that it would.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `$_.DirectoryName` returns a fully-qualified path. Also, if you wantto reference properties of an object within an expansion string, you have to  explicitly evaluate it: `"$($_.DirectoryName) "`. But you want just the parent directory name and a space, so try modifying your `-NewName` script block to `{ ($_.Name -replace $_.Directory.Name).Trim() }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `StartsWith` method to check if the files start with the folder name. Try the following cmdlets

```ps
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*.txt" | Where { $_.Name.StartsWith($_.Directory.Name) } | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace  "$($_.Directory.Name) " , ''  }
```